# Variável local dentro de um ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Eu tenho um input text dentro de um ngFor e gostaria de definir uma variavel local dinâmica que tivesse como valor um id único para cada input, para que eu consiga realizar o .focus() desse input, porém não sei como realizar isso, já tentei de diversas maneiras e não tive sucesso.

Gostaria de definir o idEmail de cada email como minha variável local
Para poder acessa-lo com meu @ViewChild

```html
<tr *ngFor="let email of Emails">
    <td *ngIf="!isUpdating(email.idEmail)">
        {{ email.enderecoEmail }}
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="isUpdating(email.idEmail)">
        <input [(ngModel)]="txtEmail" #email.idEmail type="text" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Por favor me ajudem estou presa nesta task à 2 dias e não acho a solução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Bem-vinda ao SOpt.

Bom pra resolver seu problema podemos utilizar o `attr` no `input` para definir o id do mesmo.

Ex.

```
<input attr.id="input_email_{{email.idEmail}}">
```

Depois é só capturar o mesmo e executar o que desejas.

Ex.

```
let thatemail = document.getElementById('input_email_2');

thatemail.focus();
```

Exemplo completo em: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxbhul